# How to get the data from a Bluetooth Socket in Android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm new at coding in Android. I've been following the book "Professional Android 4 App Development" I am basically trying to figure out a way to receive a bunch of strings over Bluetooth sent by any device. This is what I have so far

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up the window layout
    setContentView(R.layout.data);

    ListView myData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    final ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mData);

    //Bind Array to List View

    myData.setAdapter(aa);

    startDiscovery();

    String add = BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE;

    BluetoothDevice device = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(add);
    connectToServerSocket(device, MY_UUID);     

    mData.add(0, incoming);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

This is my onCreate and these are the classes or functions I'm not sure how to call them...

```
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceList =
    new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    private void startDiscovery() {
        registerReceiver(discoveryResult,
        new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        if (mAdapter.isEnabled() && !mAdapter.isDiscovering())
        deviceList.clear();
        mAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
        BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String remoteDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
        BluetoothDevice remoteDevice =
                intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                deviceList.add(remoteDevice);
                Log.d(TAG, "Discovered"  + remoteDeviceName);
                }
                };
```

This is my Socket:

```
private void connectToServerSocket(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid){
try{
        BluetoothSocket clientSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        clientSocket.connect();
        StringBuilder incoming = new StringBuilder();
        listenforData(clientSocket, incoming);

        transferSocket = clientSocket;
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("BLUETOOTH","Bluetooth client I/O Exception", e);
    }
}
```

And My listen for data looks like this:

```
private void listenforData(BluetoothSocket socket, StringBuilder incoming){
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        try{
            InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while(true){
        bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
        if (bytesRead != -1){
            String result = "";
            while((bytesRead == bufferSize)&&(buffer[bufferSize-1]!=0)){
            result = result + new String(buffer,0,bytesRead-1);
            bytesRead= instream.read(buffer);
            }
            result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead -1);
            incoming.append(result);
        }
        socket.close();
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Message received failed.", e);
    }
    finally{
    }
}}
```

What I am missing is how to retrieve the strings from the socket listener and place them on the ListView. I need some guidance. Am I even doing this correctly?

Comment: why not you read the dev doc here???
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
and try their sample codes??

Comment: @Tim I read that webpage and I feel I have pretty much the same code, but I am not sure how to send the data back to the OnCreate. in the example u sent me they use mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget(); I'm not really sure how can I implement that in my program. I need to add the strings to the ListView I have. any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Change ur title, it is not about BLE, is about handler, read about it Android! you need to implement receiver your onCreate! so you use handler to send data to OnCreate and receiver to get the data!